# Htaccess and GET not working

Tags: .htaccess, get

OK, I admit ... I blow at htaccess! Therefore, I now deal with it.

I want a page like:

```
index.php -> localhost
index.php?group=1 -> localhost/1(/)
index.php?group=1&page=1 -> localhost/1/1(/)
```

So far, no problem .. However, after this I would be able to add your own GET tags.
Eg. I want the URL to be:

```
localhost/audi/guestbook?do=delete&id=54
```

Here I can not get $_GET['do'] or $ _GET['id'].

My Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?group=$1 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?group=$1&page=$2
```

Grateful for sensible answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [QSA] flag to the two rewrite rules  (And the [L] flag as well:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?group=$1     [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?group=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```